# Fetching data from Application insights (Azure Portal) to display it on a web page in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I have configured my .net web application with azure portal using application insights. Now what I want is that the details that are shown in the portal should be displayed on my web page of my .net web app. I don't know hoe to do it and want someone to help me in this regard. T am also sharing the snapshot of what actually I want to fetch from my azure portal, to display as a grid report on my application's web page.
[[image: I want these two marked parts as a part of my web page, that is, one as a division and the other as a grid report.[1]]

Answer (score 6):

There's an API for retrieving data from Application Insights. From the documentation you can "Query and integrate with the performance, availability and usage data collected by Application Insights for your application" and "Access all your app's event and metric data with a powerful and simple REST API".

Some sample requests:

Return the total number of requests in the last day  (timespan=P1D):

```
GET /v1/apps/DEMO_APP/metrics/requests/count?timespan=P1D HTTP/1.1
```

Average server response time per hour (interval=PT1H) for the last 6 hours:

```
GET /v1/apps/{app-id}/metrics/requests/duration?timespan=PT6H&interval=PT1H
```

List the last 5 events:

```
GET /v1/apps/{app-id}/events/$all?$top=5
```

List GET requests which failed or took longer than 0.5 seconds:

```
GET /v1/apps/{app-id}/events/requests?$filter=startswith(request/name, 'GET') and (request/resultCode ne '200' or request/duration gt 500)
```

More info here:

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/

EDIT:

Below is how you add Application Insights:

1. Click on your App Service and then in the Overview panel you should see a link for Application Insights:

[image: App Service Overview]

2. After adding this click on the App service again and select Application Insights in the Settings section, then scroll over and select API Access:

[image: API Access]

3. Click Create API key

EDIT 2:

Ok once you create the API key you can use this along with your application ID to return data from Application Insights. You can do this using the public API which has this format:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/{version}/apps/{app-id}/{operation}/[path]?[parameters] X-API-Key:{key}
```

You can use this page to query the data or you can use something like Postman or cUrl:

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics

You'll need to provide your application ID which you'll find in your Azure portal and the API key you generated. Below is an example GET request that gets the total number of requests for the last 30 days:

```
GET /v1/apps/{yourApplicationId}/metrics/requests/count?timespan=P30D HTTP/1.1
Host: api.applicationinsights.io
x-api-key: {yourAPIKey}
```

When you have the API call working correctly you can use whatever client you want to retrieve the data  e.g. Angular, jQuery, C# HttpClient, etc.

EDIT 3:

Ok so here's a basic but complete html page to retrieve app insight data from your application. All you need to do is replace "{applicationId}" and "{api-key}" with your values. You get these in the azure portal - click on the "Application Insights" and "API Access" sections as shown in the previous screen shots.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>App Insights Sample</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script>
      function getAppInsightsData() {
        const userAction = async () => {
          const url = 'https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{applicationId}/metrics/requests/count?timespan=P30D';
          const myHeaders = { headers: new Headers({  
              'x-api-key': '{api-key}'
            })
          }
          const response = await fetch(url, myHeaders);
          const myJson = await response.json();

          document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Date Range: ' + myJson.value.start + ' to ' + myJson.value.end + '. Requests: ' + myJson.value["requests/count"].sum;
        }
        userAction();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:getAppInsightsData()">Get data using fetch</button>
    <div id='div'>
      <p id='p1'></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply......Let me check and test this solution. I'll let you know if it worked for me or not

Comment: To access your data you need the Application ID and an API key - you get them from the Application Insights resource for your application. Settings -> API Access -> Create API key

Comment: can you pleases elaborate a bit more that where can I find the Settings option to access API and create a key

Comment: and if u don't mind, can use share with me a small code example where you have shown the application insight data on the web page in a web aplication

Comment: The solution you have suggested, allows the user to limit the resources according to his/her requirement but that too will be displayed on the azure portal but not on a web page of your app. What I want is that I fetch the data from the application insights and display it on my application's web page in the browser according to my needs and than apply filters on it. Kindly if you can assist me, kindly address this issue. thanks

Comment: can you share a link to some sample code? I am totally stuck at the moment and need assistance.

Comment: @Awais does that answer your question or do you need more help?

Comment: need more assistance

Comment: @Awais see Edit 3 - I added a web page that you can use as a basis for retrieving the data. You just replace the application Id and api key as described

Comment: @Awais you're welcome, feel free to mark it as the answer if you think it answered your question