# Is there any way to get data from the application insights and display it on a web page of the asp.net application in the web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I wanted to get data from the application insights that are configured with azure portal and wanted to display it on a web page of the asp.net application in the web browser. All I can find until now is a REST API which manipulates the data according to the developers desires but it still displays the results on a the azure portal. What I need is a way to get the data from the azure portal and display it on a web page by applying different filters according to my requirements. I have searched a lot but I am not able to find any clue or a way forward. Please if someone can help me out as it is really frustrating, not to move forward despite trying and exploring as mush as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching data from Application insights (Azure Portal) to display it on a web page in asp.net web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761528/fetching-data-from-application-insights-azure-portal-to-display-it-on-a-web-pa)

Comment: As you already stated, and per answer in the other question, there is an api you can use. You can call that api in your own web app and **display the result on your site.** If you do not know how to create a chart or anything using the result from the App insights api than that is a whole other question.

Comment: @PeterBons well that API filters the results on the azure portal not on my website while I want those results to be displayed on my web page. If I am wrong at understanding kindly guide me through. And as far as this part is concerned, " If you do not know how to create a chart or anything using the result from the App insights api than that is a whole other question", I will be grateful if u could guide me or refer me to an answer, regarding this problem set as well. thanks

Comment: see #3 of https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart . You probably just pressed "try it" but that is for demonstration purposes only. You need to call the api using javascript or c#

Comment: @PeterBons well let me see..

Comment: @PeterBons and how do I create a chart or anything using the result from the App insights api? any referral

Comment: Try a library like http://www.chartjs.org/ .

Comment: @PeterBons if u don't mind can u share a small snippet or a one page app link where the application insights REST API is implemented. So that i can get an idea of what I have to do. As I am too confused right now and am just not able to proceed . Please if u can help me out here.